# How to loop over inventory host/ip and add push it through an API in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, check-mk

So I'm fairly new to Ansible. I'm trying to get the ip address and hostname from my inventory:

```
- set_fact:
    ip_out: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
    host_out: "{{hostvars[inventory_hostname].inventory_hostname}}"
```

And then want to add it in my monitoring system through an API. I'm just not sure how to make my loop work. It works when adding one host at a time but not multiple.

```
- name: Add host to Check_MK site via WebAPI
  uri:
    url: '{{ cmkclient__connection_string }}?action=add_host&_username={{ cmkclient_api_user }}&_secret={{ cmkclient_api_password }}&output_format=json'
    method: 'POST'
    body: 'request={"attributes":{"alias": "Test", "ipaddress": "{{item[0]}}", "hostname": "{{item[1]}}", "create_folders": "0", "folder": "" }'
    return_content: yes
  delegate_to: localhost
  when: '"No such host" in cmkclient__host_query.json.result'
  register: cmkclient__host_add
  changed_when: (cmkclient__host_add.json is defined) and
                (cmkclient__host_add.json.result_code == 0)
  failed_when: (cmkclient__host_add.json is not defined) or
               (cmkclient__host_add.json.result_code != 0)
  with_nested:
     - "{{ip_out}}"
     - "{{host_out}}"
```

I get a JSON parsing error.
Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, but looks like Instead of using loop and `item[0]` you could directly use `ansible_default_ipv4['address']` and `inventory_hostname` in the `body`.

Comment: You might want to look at the brand new [Checkmk Ansible Collection](https://github.com/tribe29/ansible-collection-tribe29.checkmk). We are currently working on it as a side project and keep extending the functionality. But it should already serve your needs quite nicely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you'd like to use the IP address and hostname of hosts under the targeted group for the `body` of API request. Instead of delegating this task to localhost, we could have a play on localhost like:

```yaml
# gather required facts from all hosts
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - setup:
        gather_subset: network

- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "ipaddress: {{ ip_address }}, hostname: {{ host_name }}"
      vars:
        ip_address: "{{ hostvars[item]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
        host_name: "{{ hostvars[item]['inventory_hostname'] }}"
      loop: "{{ groups['all'] }}"
```

I've used a `debug` task, but the same `loop` and `vars` can be applied to your `uri` task as well.

**Note:**

If you are running the `uri` task on `my_group` (or all) hosts, then you should be simply able to refer to the required variables directly, without delegating. In this case the task will run on each host of the group using its IP address and hostname.

```
body: 'request={"attributes":{"alias": "Test", "ipaddress": "{{ ansible_default_ipv4['address'] }}", "hostname": "{{ inventory_hostname }}", "create_folders": "0", "folder": "" }'
```

Comment: Thank you. I want to loop through every single host, not under specific groups but all of them

Comment: There's a default group called `all` for that. You just replace `my_group` with `all`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get a JSON parsing error: Checkmk exception: Failed to parse JSON request: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 129 (char 128)\"}"

Comment: Must be a syntax error, have you taken my example as it is?

Comment: Hi, yes. I just sorted it into my role

Comment: Except the "note" part ofc. I added the variable names there because Ive already tried it directly with the inventory variables